# K8s nfs static pv full, how to update "pvc/pv" using new backup nfs static pv without reinstall all

Tags: kubernetes, backup, nfs, rancher

#### Question:

I have an elastic cluster using static NFS PV. How I can move those data to another server has more space `(already did, just copy it)` and **keep the application apply new backup data without reinstalling everything**.
I use Rancher on Centos 7 (without VM Sphere).

#### What I Try:

- Update **PV** `NFS path` and `limitStorage` to new backup server but k8s don't allow it.
- Update **existing PVC** using new **PV** on a new backup server but k8s still don't allow.

error message:

> # persistentvolumeclaims "data-core-container-log-elasticsearch-data-0" was not valid:
> # * spec: Forbidden: is immutable after creation except resources.requests for bound claims

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be several solutions, this is what worked out for me taking everything that you mentioned in the above scenario.

Taken a stateful set with nfs volume claim at `10.20.4.101`, assuming nfs drive is filled up. I relocated and copied all the data to another vm `10.20.4.102`.

Now while I keep my old configurations alive, I created a new PV with `10.20.4.102` in the same namespace with a different label than the original one something like this

```
New Settings
```

```
metadata:
  name: my-pv-1
  namespace: pv-test
  labels:
    volume-type: pv-1
```

```
Old Settings
```

```
metadata:
  name: my-pv
  namespace: pv-test
  labels:
    volume-type: pv
```

This creates a new PV in your namespace you can see in the `kubectl get pv` with status `Available` while other as Bound

Now update your statefulset yaml file fields `volume-type` to the new one same as the label in new `pv` and also the change the name in `volumeClaimTemplates` to something new. Do not apply this settings now.

```
New
```

```
volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: pv-data-1
      namespace: pv-test
    selector:
       matchLabels:
       volume-type: pv-1
```

```
Old
```

```
volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: pv-data
      namespace: pv-test
    selector:
       matchLabels:
       volume-type: pv
```

As you can surely cannot apply directly which would throw an error something like `` Forbidden: updates to statefulset spec for fields other than `replicas`, `template` and `updateStrategy` are forbidden. ``.

Now either you can delete and recreate the whole `statefulset` with a slight downtime. Or you can do this small trick with `--cascade=false` flag

```
kubectl delete statefulset mystatefulset -n pv-test --cascade=false
```

This will just delete the statefulset not the pods within the stateful set, if you keep a watch on all the resources in the namespace it will delete the statefulset but not the pods or anyresources. Keeping all the applications still accessing to the applications running.

Now `apply` the updated statefulset this will create the new statefulset with a different pvc. But your pods will be still referring to the old pvc and pv.

Now just delete the pod using `kubectl delete pod mypod-0 -n pv-test`

This will delete the pod, but statefulset in the background creates a new pod with new pvc as this gets deleted. Now if you kubectl pv and pvc you will observe there will be an additional pvc and pv with `Available` will be turned into `Bound` and will be claimed by the pvc.

Manually delete all the pods, and the statefulset takes care of recreation. After everything is done, manually delete the old pvc first and then old pv later.

You might have tried all of this and know all of them, just to keep it clear I wrote all the steps here instead of vaguely explaining.

Hope this is helpful.